# Как отчистить консоль MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Запускаю mysql клиент из консоли. Бесящий вопрос: как очищать его по типу командой clear в bash, а не прожимать кнопочкой <Enter> до тех пор пока вывод не вылезет за пределы экрана?

Comment: Решение понятно: system clear. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
system cls
```

Comment: Это как?

`cls` работает в консоли `cmd`. А топикстартер интересуется очисткой консоли в `mysql`.